# Phone ringtone does not play

Tags: motorola-moto-g

M moto G 2nd gen is not playing default phone ringtone. Even if I try to select the tones from the list they don't play the sound. Rest all the tones are working properly.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is ensure your phone ringer is not on silent or that your volume is not set too low. The next thing is to check if the file itself is corrupted. Use your File Manager to play the sound directly from storage. If it plays there but still won't work as a ringer, you should backup and format your phone. Good luck.

Comment: This was it for me. Somehow, after upgrading to 5.0, all my ringtones were gone (not there at all anymore), but they still showed up in the rintones list. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, with cache piling up, your phone reacts slower to everything. The speed change is small and can't be noticed but the cache pile is the problem. Try removing Cache Data from Storage> Settings.

If it doesn't work, try restarting your phone by holding the power button for 3 seconds and shut it down. Restart it again after couple of seconds and the ringtone should be working

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed mine by setting all of my contacts to default ringtone.  Unique ring tones for each contact do not work.

Answer (score 0):

1/15/18 PROBLEM SOLVED for Moto G3: 
Settings > Sound & notification > Interruptions > When calls and notifications arrive > had been reset to: Allow only priority Interruptions. This produced a small star warning @ top of screen, with no sound or vibration for incoming calls. CHOOSE: Always interrupt: phone calls can then ring & vibrate.

Answer (score 0):

Press the up vol button and above the slider there is a little bell icon. Touch that icon and your Moto will again make your chosen ring.